# Use hand cursor only on a certain column of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am writing a form application in C#, and I have a DataGridView, which displays data from SQL server. 
These data contain a column called `Remove` and all rows for this column contain the string *Remove*. Now I want to make all cells of this column look like a button by changing the background color, and using a hand cursor.

My problem is, I cannot use a hand cursor only on this column. What I want is, when the mouse is over any rows of this `Remove` column, change the mouse pointer to a hand cursor, but not anywhere else.

```
for(int i=0; i<myDataGridView.RowCount; i++){
    myDataGridView.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

does not do what I want because the mouse pointer becomes the hand cursor everywhere on the DataGridView, rather than only on the `Remove` column.
I tried something like

```
for(int i=0; i<myDataGridView.RowCount; i++){
    myDataGridView.Columns["Remove"].Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

but this gives an error:

> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn does not contain a definition for "Cursor".

Is there any good way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: If you want column look like button, then use [DataGridViewButtonColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try tapping into the OnCellMouseEnter event of the DataGridView. Once the event fires, you can determine which column the cell is in and change the cursor as appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

use this code , it work for me

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string colname = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
           if(colname!="btnEdit" && colname!= "btnDelete")
            {
                dataGridView1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            }
        }
```